# How can I own my very personal Cloud Server?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, storage, cloud, opensource-projects

I want to own my very own personal Cloud server where I don't have to use any of third party hardware or services no subscription no chain latter etc the reason I want this type of cloud storage server so I can connect my home Electric lock system and CCTV camera via my own server

AS I have heard people talking about Nextcloud, ownCloud, Seafile etc but when I done bit of research I found even with these open source software you have to deal with licencing on some stage as describe in following link

> https://www.cloudwards.net/diy-cloud-storage-tools/

can someone please suggest which cloud server software I can use to complete my tasks
I intend to use Raspberry Pi 4 with largest TB HDD which can Pi handle on Debian 64 bit operating system

Comment: This can hardly be answered without knowing your CCTV and lock system - would you even need a cloud system or rather just a file server? Nextcloud and owncloud are open source and one pays for professional support only (I cannot comment on the others, for I don't know). Also you need to define your disk space needs from the use case side. Disk size is not really a matter normally.

Comment: The article you reference is misleading.  You can just install next cloud on a RaspberryPI. You'll need to install a web server (Apache or nginx), PHP and a database engine like Mariadb.  These are all free and open source.  Spend some time on google searching for how to setup Nextcloud from scratch. There may even be a Raspberry PI tutorial for it.

Comment: It's not misleading, they just misunderstood what the article is saying.

Comment: Yes I may have misunderstood but after reading feedback from all of you guys now I totally understand and confident to proceed with installations and thanks for the link I have tutorial on how to install owncloud on Raspberry Pi. I think I may proceed with  this material as 1st experiment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood what the article actually said.

Nextcloud (and owncloud and the others) are all open-source software, and can be downloaded for free, but you'll have to handle the installation to your raspberry pi yourself.

In Nextcloud's case, the full installation instructions can be found [here](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/installation/source_installation.html).

It's decidedly nontrivial, but neither is operating a cloud.